# Is it possible that accept return a value same as sockfd?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Is it possible that accept() return a value same as sockfd?

for example

```
int newfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
```

Is it possible `newfd == sockfd` ?

Comment: In a word -- no. (But SO won't let me comment just a word.)

Comment: *If* you observe this, then something else before (or if doing multithreading, then while) the call to `accept()` is broken. Will say: undefined behaviour has been invoked.

Comment: @rici : technically, both can be `-1` ;)

Comment: @sander: true, although calling a function with a negative fd is undefined behaviour and its possible that `accept` won't return at all in that case.

Comment: @rici : if `sockfd` is not a valid socket descriptor (like `-1`), then [`accept`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is defined to return `-1` with errno `EBADF`.

Comment: Thanks guys, i didn't think about the situation that both are (-1), it's interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

The [`accept()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) explains:

> The `accept()` system call is used with connection-based socket types (`SOCK_STREAM`, `SOCK_SEQPACKET`).  It extracts the first connection request on the queue of pending connections for the listening socket, `sockfd`, **creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file descriptor referring to that socket**.  The newly created socket is not in the listening state.  The original socket `sockfd` is unaffected by this call.

It is this **new** socket descriptor which is returned.

The `sockfd` argument is a socket that has been created with `socket()`, bound to a local address with `bind()`, and is listening for connections after a call to `listen()`.

The returned descriptor does not exist before the call to `accept()`.

Comment: <nitpick>provided that `sockfd` is a valid socket descriptor, and not `-1`</nitpick>

Comment: Thank you so much!